# The usage of StyleSheet.create and the possibility referring to its ID

Tags: react-native

Regarding to the usage of `StyleSheet.create` and as [document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html) mentioned

> Making a stylesheet from a style object makes it possible to refer to it by ID instead of creating a new style object every time.

What does `ID` mean? Is it the key of it's style object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StyleSheet` bind styles to their custom **ID's**, which means, if the style object is **redundant** it can be referenced by the **same ID** under the hood.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  selectedListItem: {
    color: 'green',
  },
});
```

You can check the **ID's** directly by logging `styles.selectedListItem`

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

```
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center"
}
});
```

If we want to use the "container" style ,we just have to mention like this in the component:

```
 style={styles.container}
```